# Svelte radio button binding is not reflected correctly

Tags: svelte

I have a svelte component with the following code:

```
<script>
  let languages = [];
  let defaultLanguage = null;
    
  $: console.log(languages, defaultLanguage);
</script>

<p>Languages:</p>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" bind:group={languages} value="English"> English
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" bind:group={languages} value="Swedish"> Swedish
</div>

<p>Default:</p>
{#each languages as lang}
  <div>
    <input type="radio" bind:group={defaultLanguage} value={lang}> {lang}
  </div>
{/each}
```

The problem occurs when I do the following:

1. Check both checkboxes
2. Select the second radio button (Swedish)
3. Uncheck the first checkbox (English)

This removes the English radio button but it also unselects the Swedish radio button. However, the defaultLanguage variable is still set to "Swedish" which is correct. If I check the first checkbox again then the Swedish radio button is selected again.

This does not happen if I instead select the English radio button in step (2) and uncheck the Swedish checkbox in step (3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the each block of the radio buttons is not a 'keyed each block` >> [the tutorial lesson](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks)

If you know the language names are unique, you can simply use the language as key >> [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c9fdc2743e86458d836f89cc0eb47634?version=3.46.4)

```
{#each languages as lang (lang)}
  <div>
    <input type="radio" bind:group={defaultLanguage} value={lang}> {lang}
  </div>
{/each}
```